# can an opengraph object be multi-page?

Tags: object, facebook-opengraph, multipage

I've searched a lot for the answer to this question - but can't find one - possibly it is just too stupid, in which case please forgive me!

I want to add og metadata to our pages, but the information for each logical object (in our case a sports team or player) can be spread across multiple actual URLs (eg /team/, /team/players/, /team/results/ are all logically part of /team/).

Can I put the same opengraph metadata on multiple pages that represent the same object?

Or alternatively, can I specify the og:url as a regex, eg: /team/* ?

Or does /team/ imply /team/* for an og:url ?

Thanks very much for any clarification, Mike

Answer (score 0):

> the information for each logical object (in our case a sports team or player) can be spread across multiple actual URLs (eg /team/, /team/players/, /team/results/ are all logically part of /team/).

Do you mean all of these URLs contain the *same* information (they are just different points of access to that info) – or do you mean the info is *spread* in „bits and pieces” over these URLs (and a user would have to visit them all to get all the info)?

I’m not sure I understand your question/problem here – but *maybe* you’re just looking for what’s called a *canonical URL* …?

Comment: Hi - I mean the latter - that the information for one logical team is found on several differnet pages with different physical URLs. So yes, the user will find different types of info about a team at different URLs (although they are all under /team/). Cheers!

Comment: Well, you could put the same meta data into each page – but under different URLs they would still be different Open Graph objects, so things like _likes_ for individual pages etc. would spread over these different objects. Maybe it’d be better if you set a canonical URL and have all the OG data under that URL …

Comment: Thanks.  Not sure the cannonical URL is a good idea in this case, s there are so many different URLs with different content for any one team.  Thanks for your comments though.

Answer (score 0):

You could call in every subpage the Open Graph API passing the parent page as object; no need to put metadata also on subpages, if you are not interested in having subpages as separate objects. This way, a like clicked on an individual page is always given to the team. You might use a custom property to specify from where the click arrived (or even the ref property, maybe).

On a side note, I would not tell that results are logically part_of the team. Although for this specific usage, it does not matter.